# Why is Cloud Firestore not working with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

If I add this line: final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

I am getting this error:

> ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.4/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:42:29: Error: The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class.
> Future tabs.add(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
> ^^^^
> ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.4/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:42:3: Error: Constructors can't have a return type.
> Try removing the return type.
> Future tabs.add(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
> ^^^^^^
> ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.4/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:46:5: Error: Constructors can't have a return type.
> Try removing the return type.
> return newDocument;
> ^
> ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.4/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:42:71: Error: Constructor bodies can't use 'async', 'async*', or 'sync*'.
> Future tabs.add(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
> ^
> ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.4/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:42:29: Error: Final field '_delegate' is not initialized by this constructor.
> Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
> Future tabs.add(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
> ^^^
> ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.4/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:11:37: Context: '_delegate' is defined here.
> final CollectionReferencePlatform _delegate;
> ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: have you tried using flutter clean?

Comment: Yes flutter clean and Invalidate caches / Restart. Did not help.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting flutter and downloading it again. It worked

Comment: Wow.. that is pretty extreme.. Did you try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: deleting .pubcache will do too

Comment: Yes I've tried flutter clean and flutter pub get. But haven't tried deleting .pubcache